# Collector current vs. temperature

Tags: transistors, math

In *The Art of Electronics* 2nd Ed. it is said that:

The Ebers-Moll equation is $$I \approx I_s(T) e^{\frac{V}{25 \, mV}}$$ and the change of voltage with temperature at **constant current** is

$$\left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I = -2.1 \frac{mV}{K}$$

The way the authors calculate relative changes in the current is

$$\frac{\Delta I}{I} = e^{\frac{- \left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I \Delta T}{25 \, mV}}$$

which indeed they use to state that a for \$\Delta T = 30 \, K\$ you get a factor of \$\approx 10\$ increase in the current.

Is there a valid reason for this or just a mistake in the book?

At first this does not make sense to me, since they are using a coefficient that was found assuming constant current in order to calculate the change in current!

**EDIT:**

In short, from the definition of \$\left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I\$ I think the right calculation is

$$ \frac{I_s(T + \Delta T)}{I_s(
T)} e^{\frac{\left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I \Delta T}{25 \, mV}} - 1 = \frac{\Delta I}{I} =  0$$

This would mean that they are actually calculating the change in *saturation* current:

$$ \frac{I_s(T + \Delta T)}{I_s(
T)} = e^{\frac{- \left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I \Delta T}{25 \, mV}} $$

Right?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  The Ebers-Moll equation does a good job in predicting Ic for Vbe.  And indeed an increase in the collector current by a factor of 10 (at room temp.) gives an increase in the Vbe voltage of about 60 mV.

Comment: I am too lazy to dig in to your question. Please check here to see if it is a known erratum:
http://artofelectronics.net/errata/

Comment: @mkeith Thanks for the errata page. I checked it and this issue is not there.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I was looking for the change in collector current with temperature at constant Vbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading some thermodynamics when I saw something that can answer my question (?!)

It holds

$$ \left. \frac{d I}{d T} \right|_V = - \left. \frac{d V}{d T} \right|_I \left. \frac{d I}{d V} \right|_T $$

The second factor can be easily calculated from the Ebers-Moll equation.

I get:
$$ \left. \frac{d I}{d T} \right|_V \approx \frac{I}{12~K}$$

Answer (score 3):

Just for your understanding: The base emitter voltage does NOT decrease if the temperature (and with it the collector current) are increasing.
The sequence is as follows: For a constant VBE voltage the collector current Ic increases for higher temperatures of the transistor body (increased carrier mobility). And the bias voltage VBE must be **externally** reduced (2mV/K) in order to bring Ic back to the former value (that is the background saying Ic=constant). This VBE reduction should be done automatically by applying voltage feedback (emitter resistorRE).

Answer (score 1):

In these formulas it assumed that the voltage across the PN junction is set externally and that it also decreases with -2.1 mV/K. If you would do that indeed the current would change significantly. In practice there would need to be some mechanism in place to control the current. A series resistor will do the trick, it will limit the current.

But then you say: but then V will be lower !

And that is correct, only the V to I relation is exponential so even though I can change a lot, V will not change much except for the -2.1 V/K.

Another complication is that Is(T) is VERY temperature dependent.

Also have a look at [this question](http://These%20formulas%20are%20only%20valid%20around%20a%20certain%20operating%20point%20at%20which%20the%20PN%20junction%20needs%20to%20be%20biased%20so%20that%20some%20some%20current%20will%20flow.%20Also%20the%20current%20is%20very%20strongly%20dependent%20on%20the%20voltage%20applied.)

Comment: That 2.1V/K coefficient only applies at a particular bias point. Just FYI. If you haven't seen it before, check out the Bob Pease article: "What's all this Vbe stuff, anyhow?" I linked to it in my comment above.

Comment: I cannot follow your calculation. I get  e^(700/25)/10000 = 1.44 * 10^8

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake there ! I completely changed my answer :-)